dmidecode Displays Incorrect Processor Manufacturer and Version on Debian 12 Guest Running on KVM with RHEL 9.4 Host, but Works Correctly on Hyper-V
I am new to Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL). I have installed RHEL 9.4 on an Intel Core i7 13th Gen machine and prepared a Debian 12 virtual machine (guest) using KVM. Within the Debian 12 guest, the dmidecode command reports incorrect values for the processor manufacturer and version. Specifically, it shows "Red Hat" as the processor manufacturer and "RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)" as the processor version, instead of the actual manufacturer and version, which are "Intel(R) Corporation" and "13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1360P," respectively.
However, when I run dmidecode on Debian 12 guests within other virtualization platforms, such as Hyper-V, Oracle VirtualBox, or VMware ESXi, it correctly reports the processor details.
root@DEB-KVM-c9a2ea07b86e45f9ad685704bfb0809d:~# dmidecode -s processor-manufacturer
Red Hat
Red Hat
Red Hat
Red Hat
root@DEB-KVM-c9a2ea07b86e45f9ad685704bfb0809d:~# dmidecode -s processor-version
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)

Environment:

Host System:

Processor: Intel Core i7 13th Gen
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4 (Plow)



  [root@localhost samadhan]# cat /etc/os-release
  NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
  VERSION="9.4 (Plow)"
  ID="rhel"
  ID_LIKE="fedora"
  VERSION_ID="9.4"
  PLATFORM_ID="platform:el9"
  PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4 (Plow)"
  ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
  LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
  CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos"
  HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
  [root@localhost samadhan]#

[root@localhost samadhan]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-427.40.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 4 15:22:45 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dmidecode behavior on Actual Host machine:
[root@localhost samadhan]# dmidecode -s processor-family
Core i7

[root@localhost samadhan]# dmidecode -s processor-manufacturer
Intel(R) Corporation

[root@localhost samadhan]# dmidecode -s processor-version
13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1360P

- Guest System: (KVM)

Operating System: Debian 12

root@debian:~# uname -a
Linux debian 6.10.6+bpo-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.10.6-1~bpo12+1 (2024-08-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@debian:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

root@DEB-KVM-c9a2ea07b86e45f9ad685704bfb0809d:~# dmidecode -t processor
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0400, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: CPU 0
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Other
        Manufacturer: Red Hat
        ID: A2 06 0B 00 FF FB 8B 0F
        Version: RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
        Voltage: Unknown
        External Clock: Unknown
        Max Speed: 2000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2000 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Other
        L1 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L2 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Core Count: 1
        Core Enabled: 1
        Thread Count: 1
        Characteristics: None

Handle 0x0401, DMI type 4, 42 bytes

dmidecode behavior
in KVM:
root@debian:~# dmidecode -s processor-manufacturer
Red Hat
Red Hat
Red Hat
Red Hat

root@debian:~# dmidecode -s processor-version
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
RHEL-9.4.0 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)

However, when I run dmidecode on Debian 12 guests within other virtualization platforms, such as Hyper-V, Oracle VirtualBox, or VMware ESXi, it correctly reports the processor details.
Here is the example of Hyper-V virtualization platform.
root@DEB-HYPV-6068a9c398774464aa501fe74c31430a:~# dmidecode -s processor-manufacturer

Intel(R) Corporation
root@DEB-HYPV-6068a9c398774464aa501fe74c31430a:~# dmidecode -s processor-version
INTEL(R) XEON(R) SILVER 4516Y+


root@DEB-HYPV-6068a9c398774464aa501fe74c31430a:~# dmidecode -t processor
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.0 present.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: None
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Xeon
        Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
        ID: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        Signature: Type 0, Family 0, Model 0, Stepping 0
        Flags: None
        Version: INTEL(R) XEON(R) SILVER 4516Y+
        Voltage: 1.6 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 4000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2200 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: None
        L1 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L2 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        Serial Number: None
        Asset Tag: None
        Part Number: None
        Core Count: 4
        Core Enabled: 4
        Thread Count: 1
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable
                Multi-Core
                Hardware Thread
                Execute Protection
                Enhanced Virtualization
                Power/Performance Control

Possible Resolution:
After googling the issue, I discovered that changing the cluster compatibility version of the Red Hat Virtualization (RHV) cluster can resolve the DMI reporting issue.
This change requires a valid subscription to Red Hat Virtualization.
Is there an option to utilize Red Hat Virtualization under a free or trial subscription?

Why is this an issue? Why do you care? Are there any real problems with running software on this virtual machine? // Just fun to notice, a "standard" Qemu (without Red Hat patches) says Product Name: Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009) and Version: pc-q35-9.0. For some reason, Red Hat moved Product Name to Version (in addition to changing strings).

If the guest boots, and you have no specific requirements to care about the exact machine, this is probably fine and no action is required.
dmidecode is correct, the host is Red Hat virtual hardware, in other words your VM host. The hardware is whatever qemu wants it to be, and isolation of guests is a security feature, so these interfaces are not going to represent physical hardware. Boot Linux on physical hardware sometime and compare, it may have hardware vendors and system information.
RHEL has a few patches to qemu-kvm with changes. Beyond branding in the descriptions, RHEL maintains some versioned machine types. Usually you do not care about the exact qemu and kernel version of your VM hosts, at say RHEL 9.4. Processor instruction set and other hardware features are usually backwards compatible quite far back.

Thank you for your response. I apologize for the incomplete dmidecode output earlier—I’ve now updated my question with the complete information. Please take a look when you have a moment.
I really appreciate your feedback, as I'm still getting familiar with virtualization concepts.
Thanks again for your assistance!

In guest, the hardware looks like whatever the hypervisor software wants it to. An accurate hardware inventory will not be from in guest.

Thank you so much for your response and for taking the time to help me with this issue. I really appreciate the insights you provided, and I’ve learned a lot from the feedback and discussions here.
Thanks again for your support.

After some research and learning from the responses, I now understand that KVM is a type-1 hypervisor, meaning it runs directly on the host's hardware. This allows KVM to present the virtualized hardware, and in my case, the CPU manufacturer and version are shown as Red Hat because the "hardware" in my virtual machine is provided by the KVM hypervisor.
On the other hand, platforms like Oracle VirtualBox are type-2 hypervisors, which run on top of an operating system rather than directly on the hardware. This explains why the behavior of dmidecode might differ depending on the hypervisor in use.
For anyone interested, here's more information on KVM: What is KVM?.
I’d like to thank the community members for helping improve my understanding of how hypervisors work.

The thing you are observing is not related to the hypervisor type at all. All types of them do some peripheral emulation and all are free to present them to a guest as they like. A proper example of type-1 hypervisor could be Xen, which does nothing except managing virtualization and it requires dom0 (with it's device drivers) to actually access real peripherals. I'd argue that KVM is neither type-1 nor type-2; it's something of a "middle ground": it's built into the operating system kernel; it's not situated above that kernel (as in classical type-1) or below that kernel (as in type-2).
